# Obtener un dato antes de una coma JAvascript

Tags: javascript

Hola amigos tengo el siguiente arreglo

```
 datos = ["1,andres", "2, julian", "3,juan", "12,carlos"]
```

quiero obtener los numeros de cada elemento.

tengo esto pero creo que necesito el indice de la coma para poder decirle al substr que me elimine apartir de la posicion dada por la , usare indexof

```
 datos.map(element => {
            
                console.log(element.substr(0, 2));
        })
```

Comment: Que tal, nos comentas que has intentado para poder guiarte en el proceso.

Comment: Pues es que estoy haciendolo en paralelo, estoy usando un .filter para buscar la coma pero no se como extraer los datos antes de la coma, pienso en crear una variable con un arreglo vacio y hacer .push de los datos encontrado pero para nada funciona

Comment: insert.userInsert.map(element => {
            
                console.log(element.substr(0, 2));
        })

Comment: Aun pienso que debes editar tu pregunta, indicando lo que has hecho y que es lo que esperas obtener, yo entiendo que quisieras obtener un arreglo de numeros es asi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con la función `split` y usar la coma como separador, luego tomas lo que esté en la posición 0 que es el índice:

```js
 datos = ["1,andres", "2, julian", "3,juan", "12,carlos"]
 
indices = datos.map(d => d.split(',')[0])
 
console.log(indices)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias maneras de hacerlo.
Te dejo aquí la variante del regex:

```
const datos = ["1,andres", "2, julian", "3,juan", "12,carlos"]

datos.map((dato) => {
    const match = dato.match(/(\d+),/gm)
    const numero = match[0].replace(',', '')
    console.log(numero)
})
```

Comment: Gracias, la verdad estaba pensando usar el .map pero con el .map queria sacar el indice de la posicion del ultimo numero y eliminarlo con substr pero me tope con el problema de que el numero era un 12 entonces me tomaria la posicion del 1 y no del 2